Unicode strings in a purely python3 codebase - are these useless?
In the codebase that I'm working on, there seems to be remnants of python2 because a lot of the strings are prefixed with u.
From researching, it looks like this denotes a unicode string, but in python3, all strings are unicode by default. If I did a big passthrough of the codebase and removed all the u's before strings, would there be any downside?

The downside would be you'd be on the git blame for all those lines. You could add the git hash of the commit to .git-blame-ignore-revs to mitigate that.

I don't really think the duplicate applies here, this doesn't ask what are unicode strings, but if the trailing u can be removed safely.

Yes, if you are sure that your code won't be executed with python 2 you can safely remove them, they are meaningless in python 3.
The unicode strings in python 3 were only allowed to facilitate porting code from python 2 to python3 (see PEP414). Using unicode strings was even a syntax error before python 3.3.
Removal of the u is done automatically by code formatting tools like black:
Original code:
s = u"abc"

After reformatting with black:
s = "abc"

